# Help finding/installing kernel headers-3.11.0-14-generic

Tags: 13.10, kernel

I just switched to Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm trying to install VMplayer in order to run windows based applications. The installation went good but when I try to open VMplayer it displays an error saying that several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.
Specifically is asking for 
Kernel headers-3.11.0-14-generic

How can I locate this file and/or install it properly?

A step by step answer will be much appreciated...
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have this package [linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic)

It can be installed by running the command below, just a single step.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your kernal by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```